# How to develop and deploy add-ons for IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, add-on, bho, ieaddon

can someone answer any of these questions?

1. Is it possible to develop an add-on for IE 11 with access to networking APIs (UDP/TCP sockets)?
2. Is there any website like Chrome Web Store for publishing add-ons?
3. Is there a way to install an add-on from a webpage?
4. Would it be the same IE 11 add-on development and deployment processes for windows phone and windows desktop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default IE add-ons have very limited rights but you can elevate it, as I understand. Some details are [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx).
And take a look on [this project](https://github.com/trigger-corp/browser-extensions), it can be relevant.